# C functions with two round brackets pairs?

Tags: c, vlfeat

I'm sorry for the bad title, but nothing better came to my mind apart from "I don't understand this code". Please, feel free to propose a modification.

I'm reading [this](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/f363f3abf9e55cb117fdbdcdfe44b95ec838ca5f/vl/vlad.c) code. I've never seen a C function like this one:

```
static void
VL_XCAT(_vl_vlad_encode_, SFX)
(TYPE * enc,
 TYPE const * means, vl_size dimension, vl_size numClusters,
 TYPE const * data, vl_size numData,
 TYPE const * assignments,
 int flags)
{
    // function body
}
```

In particular I'm confused by `(_vl_vlad_encode_, SFX)`. Up to know, all the functions headers that I've seen had only one "pair of round brackets" (the function's parameters), while here there are two pairs.

What does it mean the first one? I think that this is linked to later calls `_vl_vlad_encode_f` and `_vl_vlad_encode_d`, which don't appears anywhere else in the library code, but I can't understand how they're connected.

Comment: Perhaps `VL_XCAT` is a macro? Or it's a function that returns a function pointer?

Comment: `VL_XCAT` is just a [macro](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/f363f3abf9e55cb117fdbdcdfe44b95ec838ca5f/vl/host.h#L112) which concatenates the two input parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VL_XCAT` is a macro usually used to concatenate two tokens. (`A ## B`) which means it'll create a token from both arguments which is:
`_vl_vlad_encode_`
and
`SFX` - is probably define for type of floating point variable used (`double`/`float`)

I would say this'll choose between double and float function to use and use `_vl_vlad_encode_f`  or `_vl_vlad_encode_d` based on defines.

So if

```
#define SFX d
```

it'll create `_vl_vlad_encode_d` after processing this line.

Comment: Goddamit C, why they didn't came up with templates early? This code style is simply horrible

Answer (score 2):

The `VL_XCAT` and `VL_CAT` function-like macros are in `vl/host.h` (same directory as the `vlad.c` file you linked).

`VL_CAT(x,y)` simply concatenates its arguments and `VL_XCAT(x,y)` is the same, except its arguments are macro-eXpanded:

```
#define VL_CAT(x,y) x##y
#define VL_XCAT(x,y) VL_CAT(x, y)
```

`VL_XCAT(_vl_vlad_encode_, SFX)` results in `_vl_vlad_encode_f` or `_vl_vlad_encode_d`, depending on how `SFX` is defined.

So you end up with this, for example, when `#define SFX d` is used (note that `#define TYPE double` is active at the same time):

```
static void
_vl_vlad_encode_d
(double * enc,
 double const * means, vl_size dimension, vl_size numClusters,
 double const * data, vl_size numData,
 double const * assignments,
 int flags)
{
    // function body
}
```

Looks like a normal function definition now, doesn't it?